# Directive (nested inside a partial) throws “Termplate must have exactly one root element”

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to follow angular best practice recommendation and use directives to
 encapsulate reusuable HTML elements.
The error message:

> Error: Template must have exactly one root element. was: partials/user/path/to/somedata.html

the directive code:

```
.directive('stDirectivename', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        // transclude: false,
        template: 'partials/user/path/to/somedata.html'
    };
})
```

And the template:

```
<div ng-show="person.condition" class="someclass">
    <span class = "personRoi">
        <i class="anotherclass " ng-class="{'specialclass1': person.count>=0,'specialclass2':person.count<0}">

        </i>{{person.somedata}}%
    </span>
</div>
```

Called in the partial (which is the template of a modal) as:
`<st-directivename></st-directivename>`

when I replace the template url for a simple html string in the directive. Everything works. Unfortunately I can't do that for the real template that involves both `'` and`“`. besides this solution won't scale to the larger templates I plan to some directives.

Also when I just insert the template html instead of the directive tag, everything works correctly (I'm actually extracting the code from the existing html to make it reusable).

I read in other SO questions that this has to do with having extra space/tags/comments in the template. But I just can't find such elements.

Does anybody know a solution for this? I'll be glad for any help.

Comment: Explained here http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile:tplrt and here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459

Comment: 1) The template file can't have leading or trailing white-space characters (including line-feeds).  2) The template you've pasted is missing a closing `</div>` (and contains a leading white-space)...

Comment: @J.Bruni sorry, this is just a SO slip, fixed now to show the template, the div is closed and no leading white space

Comment: Trailing <!-- comments --> in the template can also create this error, I've discovered.

Comment: @J.Bruni said it right!  I just wasted a ton of time trying various solutions when all I had to do was remove some html comments from a directive html....uggg!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your mistake is: you must use `templateUrl` rather than `template` so as to indicate the path to the html partial

```
.directive('stDirectivename', function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        replace:true,
        //transclude:false,
        templateUrl:'partials/user/path/to/somedata.html'

    };
})
```

Answer (score 6):

For those that may come after, also note that directive templates need to have --as the error says-- only one root element i.e. multiple spans or divs must be enclosed in a root div.

Also note the comments on the OP: Whitespace or trailing comments in the template may result in this error as well.

It appears a fix to make Angular less temperamental about this may be included in the next release/update: [github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459](http://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459)

Comment: Indeed my template started with a html comment, it imported the template after removing the comment.

Comment: very helpful! my template has commented html and it causes this error as well. After I removing the commented html everything works.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still looking for further clues...I ran into this same error when I had a typo in the templateUrl path of the directive. You get this error if you have `replaced: true`. Otherwise, you may see more wild error as `WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once`, which took me quite a while to figure out because the error message is really misleading.

Comment: But if I want to use ```replace:true``` is there another way to fix the errors?