# "Invalid Template Root" error

Tags: angularjs, playframework-2.0, angularjs-directive

I am using AngularJS for the front end of my Play 2.0 application. I loosely followed Paul Dijou's [blog post](http://pauldijou.fr/blog/2013/02/17/angularjs-routing-playframework/) for setting up HTML5 routing. Basically, Play framework serves the `index.html` file for every unknown route, and from there AngularJS routing takes over.

In my application I have moved my navigation bar into a directive. This works fine when I initially load my application. But when I do a refresh after navigating "deeper" into my Angular app, Angular throws an `Invalid Template Root` error for my `navbar directive. As you can see below, the template has exactly one root element, just as required.

I already checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676326/directive-nested-inside-a-partial-throws-termplate-must-have-exactly-one-root), but I am using the `templateUrl` attribute.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JrgxAXmboTwSWsrMCC9s) (Content stripped, but otherwise accurate)

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**Directive:**

```
myDirectives.directive("navbar", function() {
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        replace : true,
        templateUrl : "assets/app/partials/navbar.html"
    };
});
```

**Template** (`navbar.html`)**:**

```
<div ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        ... (There is more content here but the problem occurs even if this content is removed)
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Show navbar.html source

Comment: Have you been able to recreate this in isolation using something like jsFiddle? I suspect there is more going on, but it's not immediately obvious what the problem might be from this code.

Comment: @Stewie I already included a snippet from the `navbar.html` source. I have double-checked that all tags are close and that there are no trailing spaces, etc.

Comment: Without fiddle/plunker, hard to tell.

Comment: @Josh I haven't tried to recreate this in isolation because I thought it may be related to Play framework. I might be able to create a minimal version on my local machine but I guess it wouldn't be easily possible to create a jsFiddle which takes all possibly relevant issues into account.

Comment: @Stewie I added a plunker, hope it helps.

Comment: Your plunker has an unrelated error, and it doesn't reproduce the error as described in question.

Comment: @Stewie I fixed the error in my plunker. As I mentioned before, I suspect the issue to be related to the combination of Angular and Play framework and I am not able to reproduce the error inside jsFiddle or Plunker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing your relative template URL with an absolute one:

```
// Note the leading '/'.
// You could also try a full URL, although that makes development hard.
templateUrl : "/assets/app/partials/navbar.html"
```